# How to verify Azure App Service generated domain with Google Cloud Console?

Tags: azure, dns, google-oauth, google-cloud-console

Let's say I created an app service (Web App) in Azure, whether it is for a fronted side or backend API. A custom domain name is created for this service during setup. Along with it, I have Google Cloud OAuth credentials that need a domain(s) used in it to be verified in order for an app to be submitted (published). The question is, how do I verify this custom domain generated for a web app service in Azure with Google Cloud Console?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the right approach to try to verify the custom generated domain since you wouldn't be the owner of the domain name (microsoft would be the actual owner)

I would recommend the following:

1. Get/register a domain which you own
2. authorize the domain in Azure App Service
3. Create a CNAME record in the domain you register, with the value of the generated domain name in Azure App Service.

This way you should be able to make the integration with Google Cloud Console with Azure App Service